# Testing a get/set with Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm trying to test the set of a property, but I don't know how I can do it in this particular case. 
I'm using .NET 4.5 and Moq framework.

I've this method:

```
 public Invoice Approve(Invoice invoiceToBeApproved)
{
    var approvedInvoiceStatus = InvoiceStatusRepository.First<ApprovedStatus>();

    invoiceToBeApproved.Car.RemainingSeats -= 1;

    if (invoiceToBeApproved.Car.RemainingSeats < 0)
    {
        throw new BusinessException("There are no remaining seats");
    }

    invoiceToBeApproved.InvoiceStatus = approvedInvoiceStatus;

    InvoiceRepository.Update(invoiceToBeApproved);

    context.SaveChanges();

    return invoiceToBeApproved;
}
```

I'm doing a unit test (not integration test, so I'm not going to the db).

What I want to test is

```
invoiceToBeApproved.Car.RemainingSeats -= 1;
```

I tried using VerifyGet, but I just can't reach that property.

Part of my test is this

```
var newInvoice = InvoiceService.ApproveInvoice(invoice);
InvoiceStatusRepository.Verify(x => x.First<ApprovedStatus>());
InvoiceRepository.Verify(x => x.Update(It.IsAny<Invoice>()));
context.Verify(x => x.SaveChanges(), Times.Exactly(1));
```

How can I test the set/get of RemainingSeats?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why use Moq for this? If `Invoice` is a POCO just check the properties with standard asserts.

Comment: And if `invoice` is a mock, would you mind sharing how it was instantiated?

Comment: @DavidPfeffer You're totally right, I didn't see that I could have check it just with an Assert!.
If you put your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Why bother unit testing properties at all?

Comment: @sgrassie: what's the problem with that? OP's not testing getter/setter but rather logic that performs that decrement.

Comment: Added the answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should use Moq at all for this. Assuming `Invoice` is a POCO, just assert the value of the property.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that you don't need to use Moq in this case. Anyhow this is how you could test it.

```
public class BusinessLogicClass
{
    public void MethodUnderTest(IFoo foo)
    {
        foo.Bar -= 1;
    }
}

public interface IFoo
{
    int Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}

[TestMethod]
public void PropertyTest()
{
    const int expected = 41;
    var foo = new Foo { Bar = 42 };
    var sut = new BusinessLogicClass();
    sut.MethodUnderTest(foo);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, foo.Bar);
}

[TestMethod]
public void PropertyTestWithMoq()
{
    var fooMoq = new Mock<IFoo>();
    var sut = new BusinessLogicClass();
    sut.MethodUnderTest(fooMoq.Object);
    fooMoq.Verify(x => x.Bar, Times.Once);
}
```